# Tengo el siguiente array agrupado por el campo name de mi array, lo que deseo es reducir los elementos de cada grupo

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente array agrupado por el campo name de mi array, lo que deseo es reducir los elementos de cada grupo por el campo c_prod, es decir si en que si tengo dos veces el mismo c_prod en el grupo reducirlo a 1 sumando el campo s_cant que es la cantidad, manteniendo el s_vent que es el precio de venta

```js
const categories = [
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 15, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 10, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 10, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '03' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 15, name: 'lucas lopez', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 15, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 10, name: 'lucas lopez', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 10, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '03' },
    { s_cant: 3, s_vent: 10, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 4, s_vent: 15, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
];

const agrupado = categories.reduce((p,c)=>{

                const group = c.name.replace(/ /g,"_");
                if(group in p){
                    p[group].push(c);
                }
                else{
                    p[group] = [c];
                }
                return p;
                },{});


                const resultado = Object.keys(agrupado).map(g=>{    
                 return [{l_client:g.replace(/_/g," ")}].concat(agrupado[g]);
                });
                var array = resultado;
                for ( var element = 0; element < array.length; element++ ) {
                    var acumulador = 0;
                    for ( var element_suma = 1; element_suma < array[element].length; element_suma++ ) {
                        acumulador += ( parseFloat(array[element][element_suma].s_vent)) * ( parseFloat(array[element][element_suma].s_cant));
                    }
                    array[element][0]['total'] = acumulador;
                }

                console.log(array);
```

**el resultado que desearía obtener**

```js
 [
  [
    {
      "l_client": "juan carlos",
      "total": 80
    },
    {
      "s_cant": 3,
      "s_vent": 10,
      "name": "juan carlos",
      "prod": "carne",
      "c_prod": "02"
    },
    {
      "s_cant": 5,
      "s_vent": 10,
      "name": "juan carlos",
      "prod": "pollo",
      "c_prod": "01"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "l_client": "fredy alarcon olivera",
      "total": 60
    },
    {
      "s_cant": 2,
      "s_vent": 10,
      "name": "fredy alarcon olivera",
      "prod": "pollo",
      "c_prod": "01"
    },
    {
      "s_cant": 4,
      "s_vent": 10,
      "name": "fredy alarcon olivera",
      "prod": "carne",
      "c_prod": "02"
    }
  ],
  [
       {
          "l_client": "lucas lopez",
          "total": 30
       },
       {
         "s_cant": 1,
         "s_vent": 10,
         "name": "lucas lopez",
         "prod": "carne",
         "c_prod": "02"
       },
       {
         "s_cant": 2,
         "s_vent": 10,
         "name": "lucas lopez",
         "prod": "pollo",
         "c_prod": "01"
       }
     ]
   ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te propongo una estructura que parece más lógica, donde cada elemento del arreglo es un objeto con 3 propiedades: Nombre de cliente, importe de venta y un arreglo con detalle de productos:

```
[
  {
    "l_client": "juan carlos",
    "total": 95,
    "prods": [
      {
        "s_cant": 3,
        "s_vent": 15,
        "name": "juan carlos",
        "prod": "carne",
        "c_prod": "02"
      },
      {
        "s_cant": 5,
        "s_vent": 10,
        "name": "juan carlos",
        "prod": "pollo",
        "c_prod": "01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "l_client": "fredy alarcon olivera",
    "total": 80,
    "prods": [
      {
        "s_cant": 2,
        "s_vent": 10,
        "name": "fredy alarcon olivera",
        "prod": "pollo",
        "c_prod": "01"
      },
      {
        "s_cant": 4,
        "s_vent": 15,
        "name": "fredy alarcon olivera",
        "prod": "carne",
        "c_prod": "02"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "l_client": "lucas lopez",
    "total": 35,
    "prods": [
      {
        "s_cant": 1,
        "s_vent": 15,
        "name": "lucas lopez",
        "prod": "carne",
        "c_prod": "02"
      },
      {
        "s_cant": 2,
        "s_vent": 10,
        "name": "lucas lopez",
        "prod": "pollo",
        "c_prod": "01"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Lo puedes hacer con un solo `.reduce()`, sin necesidad de agrupar primero.

```js
const categories = [
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 15, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 10, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 10, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '03' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 15, name: 'lucas lopez', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 15, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 10, name: 'lucas lopez', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 10, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '03' },
    { s_cant: 3, s_vent: 10, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 4, s_vent: 15, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
];

const resultado = categories.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Verificar si ya existe el elemento
    let index = acc.findIndex(item => item.l_client == cur.name);
    if(index < 0) {
        // No existe, hay que insertar y actualizar índice
        index = acc.length;
        // Se crea un objeto con 3 propiedades, donde prods es un arreglo
        acc.push({
            l_client: cur.name,
            total: 0,
            prods: []
        });
    }
    // Buscar producto
    let prodIndex = acc[index].prods.findIndex(item => item.c_prod == cur.c_prod);
    if(prodIndex < 0) {
        // No existe el producto, hay que insertarlo
        acc[index].prods.push({
            s_cant: cur.s_cant,
            s_vent: cur.s_vent,
            name: cur.name,
            prod: cur.prod,
            c_prod: cur.c_prod
        });
    } else {
        // Sí existe, hay que actualizar cantidad
        acc[index].prods[prodIndex].s_cant += cur.s_cant;
    }
    // Actualizar total
    acc[index].total += (cur.s_cant * cur.s_vent);
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(resultado);
```

Esto simplifica la lógica, tanto para crear el arreglo como para acceder posteriormente. Aunque, si lo quieres con el formato expuesto en tu pregunta, también se puede; revisa el siguiente fragmento:

```js
const categories = [
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 15, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 10, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 10, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '03' },
    { s_cant: 1, s_vent: 15, name: 'lucas lopez', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 15, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 10, name: 'lucas lopez', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 2, s_vent: 10, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '03' },
    { s_cant: 3, s_vent: 10, name: 'juan carlos', prod: 'pollo', c_prod: '01', province: '02' },
    { s_cant: 4, s_vent: 15, name: 'fredy alarcon olivera', prod: 'carne', c_prod: '02', province: '01' },
];

const resultado = categories.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Verificar si ya existe el elemento
    let index = acc.findIndex(item => item[0].l_client == cur.name);
    if(index < 0) {
        // No existe, hay que insertar y actualizar índice
        index = acc.length;
        // Se inserta un arreglo con un solo objeto
        acc.push([{
            l_client: cur.name,
            total: 0,
        }]);
    }
    // Buscar producto
    let prodIndex = acc[index].findIndex(item => item.c_prod == cur.c_prod);
    if(prodIndex < 1) {
        // No existe el producto, hay que insertarlo
        acc[index].push({
            s_cant: cur.s_cant,
            s_vent: cur.s_vent,
            name: cur.name,
            prod: cur.prod,
            c_prod: cur.c_prod
        });
    } else {
        // Sí existe, hay que actualizar cantidad
        acc[index][prodIndex].s_cant += cur.s_cant;
    }
    // Actualizar total
    acc[index][0].total += (cur.s_cant * cur.s_vent);
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(resultado);
```